# connection to local raven instance doesn't work using https

Tags: iis, ravendb

I am trying to run a client application on the same server that hosts our IIS-hosted raven server (build 2947).  The IIS site that hosts raven is bound to an SSL certificate/hostname - we would like to enforce secure requests only (and redirect http requests to https). When I set the connection to use the https protocol:

```
Url=https://ravendb.somewhere.net;Database=StaffDb
```

I get a 401 denied error when the connection is opened.  If I disable the redirect and connect to localhost non-securely, it works fine:

```
Url=http://localhost;Database=StaffDb
```

[The docs suggest SSL can only be enabled when running as a service](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/server/deployment/enabling-ssl) - does this mean our scenario of running within a secure IIS site is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Ayende Rahien for support provided offline, it turned out this issue is actually due to a feature of IIS itself:

> Windows XP SP2 and Windows Server 2003 SP1 include a loopback check
>   security feature that is designed to help prevent reflection attacks
>   on your computer. Therefore, authentication fails if the FQDN or the
>   custom host header that you use does not match the local computer
>   name.

[Ayende's blog provides some more context](http://ayende.com/blog/16385/more-auth-issues-0xc000006d-on-windows-2008-r2), and I fixed this by following steps outlined in [a Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-gb):

> **Method 2: Disable the loopback check (less-recommended method)** The second method is to disable the loopback check by setting the
>   DisableLoopbackCheck registry key.
>
> To set the DisableLoopbackCheck registry key, follow these steps:
>
> .....
>   2. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
>   3. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:
>    **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa**
>   4. Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
>   5. Type **DisableLoopbackCheck**, and then press ENTER.
>   6. Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
>   7. In the Value data box, type **1**, and then click OK.
>   8. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart your computer.

Answer (score 1):

When using SSL, you *must* use the specified hostname in the certificate.

Comment: That's what I am doing - ravendb.somewhere.net is the "Issued To" in our certificate.  Specifying this in our connection string gives a 401 error?